# Asp GridView make hyperlink column editable

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have asp:GridView. I can edit all columns without problems, except this one:

```
<asp:TemplateField>                                  
<ItemTemplate>                                            
    <asp:HyperLink ID="hyperlinkEdocs"  runat="server" Target="HyperLink" 
    HeaderText="Dopolnitve (eDocs)" 
    NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("http://{0}", Eval("CUSTOMER").ToString()) %>' 
    Text='<%# Eval("CUSTOMER") %>'></asp:HyperLink>                                                                                                               
</ItemTemplate>
```

I am editing columns by click on 'Edit' link (this triggers that columns content is displayed in a text boxes).
How can I make this column editable, so I will be able to edit and update hyperlink in column?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvrecords"  AutoGenerateColumns="false"
HeaderStyle-BackColor="#7779AF" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" DataKeyNames="UserId">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# Bind("Name", "~/Images/{0}") %>' runat="server"/>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="UserName" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView
```

Comment: Doesn't work. When I click 'edit',  it still stays as non-editable. Link is not changed into text box.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to do because I can't see your code behind but why don't you use an edit item template?

Comment: That is my problem - when I use BoundField, the localhost is prepended on the link. Otherwise, I would simply use BoundField and that's it. What happens with BoundField, example: link www.google.com becomes (when I click on it): mylocalhost.com/www.google.com -> how can I get rid of this prepended value?

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="100px"   HeaderText = "ABC">

    <ItemTemplate>

        <asp:Label ID="label" runat="server"

                Text='<%# Eval("id")%>'></asp:Label>

    </ItemTemplate>

    <EditItemTemplate>

        <asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" Width="100px" Height="50px" runat="server"

            Text='<%# Eval("id")%>'></asp:TextBox>

    </EditItemTemplate>



                                 <HeaderStyle Width="80px" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />



                                 <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />



</asp:TemplateField>
```

Edit link click open textbox

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        grd_view();
    }
```